# FCM Push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on FCM, but only below method is getting called.

```
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message
    NSLog(@"This is the message whole structure%@", remoteMessage.appData);
    NSLocalizedString(@"This is remote message%@", remoteMessage);
    NSString * msg = [remoteMessage.appData objectForKey:@"message"];
    NSLog(@"msg %@",msg);
    [self alertStatus:msg:@"Alert"];
}
```

And I got full message from server from this above method only. But none of the push notification methods are  getting called.I am not receiving any push notification, so I am unable to receive notification in background.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your backend server developer to add `notification` key in your payload like this

```
{
    "to" : " ...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
```

If you want to show notifications for user you should use `notification` key in your payload.

[Reference 1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

[Reference 2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

Comment: Are you sure this is backend problem? because even didRecieveRemoteNotification method is also not getting called.

Comment: Yeah if there is no "notification" key in playload ,the method will not call. Because that's not notification.