# FCM notifications not working in background - delegate methods also not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM notifications not working in background - delegate methods also not being called.

I know this is a repeated question. I have gone through all the solutions but no luck.

The delegate method is not being called when the app is in background and when application come from background to foreground then all the earlier notifications are getting delivered.

I have set the priority = high and "content_available" = 1 and tried too.
Here is my code:

```
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
@import FirebaseMessaging;
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
@end
#endif
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
#endif
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
@implementation AppDelegate
NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];
    self.defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //[self.defaults setObject:@"1" forKey:@"remember"];
    [FIRApp configure];
    self.selectedIndexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            }];
            [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
        }
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
     return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[Messaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }
    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UILocalNotification *not = [UILocalNotification new];
[not setAlertTitle:@"Title"];
    [not setAlertBody:@"Body"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:not];
    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[Messaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }
    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    NSLog(@"Received data message: %@", remoteMessage.appData);
}
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[Messaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }
    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}
// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set [Messaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel to YES.
#endif
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    NSLog(@"remoteMessage  1234 :%@",remoteMessage.appData);
    NSString *notResStr = remoteMessage.appData[@"data"];
    self.notificationArray = [notResStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    UILocalNotification *not = [UILocalNotification new];
    NSLog(@"self.notificationArray :%@",self.notificationArray);
    for (int i =0 ; i<self.notificationArray.count; i++) {
        if([(NSString *) [self.notificationArray objectAtIndex:i] containsString:@"\"title\""]){
            NSString *title = [self.notificationArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSArray *arr = [title componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
            [not setAlertTitle:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];
        }
        if([(NSString *) [self.notificationArray objectAtIndex:i] containsString:@"\"message\""]){
            NSString *title = [self.notificationArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSArray *arr = [title componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
            [not setAlertBody:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];
        }
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:not];
}
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }
    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
    completionHandler();
}
#endif
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    [self.defaults setObject:refreshedToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [self connectToFcm];
}
- (void)connectToFcm {
    if (![[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]) {
        return;
    }
    [self.defaults setObject:[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token] forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    NSLog(@"fcm back");
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
        } else {
        }
    }];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didRefreshRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
     // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // for development
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken");
    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
    // for production
       // [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];
    NSLog(@"APNs device token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);
    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs device token here.
    // [Messaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
    }
#pragma mark Shared Instance

+ (AppDelegate*) sharedInstance{
    return (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    NSLog(@"app is in background");
//    [self connectToFcm];
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connectToFcm];
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.defaults synchronize];
}
@end
```

receiving payload response like this

```
    {data = "{\"Nick\":\"Mario\",\"Room\":\"PortugalVSDenmark\"}";
from = 608855029366;notification = "{\"body\":\"Test Body\",\"title\":\"Test Title\"}";to = "my fcm ID";priority : "high";content-available : "1";}
```

even notification string is there in payload the delegate method is not calling when the app is in background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM Push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109567/fcm-push-notification)

Comment: @himanth I am getting the variable notification in my payload. But still the delegate method is not calling when the app is in background.Here is my response payload.{
 data = "{\"Nick\":\"Mario\",\"Room\":\"PortugalVSDenmark\"}";
 from = 608855029366;
 notification = "{\"body\":\"Test Body\",\"title\":\"Test Title\"}";
 to = "my fcmId"
}

Comment: @himanth any idea ?

Comment: hi , i have the same problem . do you know how to send that content_available: true , through FCM message console ? i am sending content_available: true through FCM message console but i am getting normal notification only , not the silent notification . what should i do ? like you said , we have to send in options , then how could i send like that ?